# Use function on all elements in document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a little plugin to check if an element is in position : fixed and to get it's height if it is. What I want is to run this function  through all elements in my document to find all fixed elements and get their heights, but I dont know how to write it down

```
$.fn.isFixed = function () {
    if ($(this).css('position') === 'fixed'){
        var height = ($(this).height());
        return height;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    };
}
```

This is my code.

Comment: so you want to return an array?

Comment: Ouch... There will be an array... That doesnt work for me. I want to go through all fixed elements to compare their height to my item's position later. I want to check if there are any fixed elements, and if there are I want to get height and compare to my other statements one by one

Answer (score 0):

In that case you may have to return an array since there can be more than one element. Also to make sure that the value indexes are maintained I'm inserting `undefined` to the array if the position is not fixed

```
$.fn.isFixed = function () {
    var array = [];

    this.each(function(){
        if ($(this).css('position') === 'fixed') {
            array.push($(this).height());
        }else{
            array.push(undefined);
        }
    })

    return array;
}
```

Comment: I dont know what I'm doing wrong, but when I type in console $('body').isFixed() is returning [undefined] even if there is a fixed element inside it. How can I call this function propertly/

Answer (score 0):

```
var allElements = $("*").contents();
```

Then use .each() function on allElements variable.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This search only in declared stylesheets.

```
var selectorsArray = [];
for (i in document.styleSheets) {
    for (k in document.styleSheets[i].cssRules) {
        if (document.styleSheets[i].cssRules[k].style.position === "fixed") {
            selectorsArray.push(document.styleSheets[i].cssRules[k].selectorText);
        }
    }
}
```

So the rest of elements you can select with:

```
$('[style~=fixed]').each(function(i,e){});
```